# What exactly do these 3 lines of C code do?

Tags: c, hash, bit-manipulation

I've been trying to parse them for a couple days, and I can't quite grok it. Here they are:

```
int left = S->buflen >> 3;
int fill = 64 - left;
if(left && (((datalen >> 3) & 0x3F) >= (unsigned)fill)){
   some code here
}
```

If it helps, this is in the reference implementation of the SHA-3 candidate BLAKE256.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? What bitwise operators do?

Comment: No, I understand bitwise operators just fine. The part that is really confusing me is dividing 'datalen' by 8 and ANDing the result with '00111111'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative without bitops might help clear up the meaning:

```
int left = S->buflen / 8;
int fill = 64 - left;
if (left != 0) {
    int tmp = datalen / 8;
    if ((tmp % 64) >= (unsigned)fill) {
        /* Some code here */
    }
}
```

This of course assumes that `buflen` and `datalen` are nonnegative, since the right shift operator has platform-dependent behavior for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
int left = S->buflen >> 3;
```

Get the number of bytes left, assuming `buflen` is a measurement in bits.

```
int fill = 64 - left;
```

Get the number of bytes that you'll therefore need to append to round up to a multiple of 64. Note that if `S->buflen` is 0 you'll end up appending an entire 64 bytes when you needn't append any, so...

```
if(left && (((datalen >> 3) & 0x3F) >= (unsigned)fill)){
   some code here
}
```

... do the some code here only if there were some bits left and `datalen`, converted from bits to bytes, mod 64 is at least equal to the number of extra bytes you'd need to write. Presumably because `datalen` is the maximum output size?

Comment: Yes — just as taking the final two digits of a base 10 number is the same as mod 100, taking the final six digits of a binary number (by ANDing) is the same as mod 64.